# URI routing for shinydashboard using shiny.router

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Suppose you have a simple `shinydashboard` which contains links created with `menuItem` and pages created with `tabItems`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

skin <- Sys.getenv("DASHBOARD_SKIN")
skin <- tolower(skin)
skin <- "blue"

## ui.R ##
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets",
             badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            h2("Dashboard tab content")
    ),
    
    tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
    )
  )
)

# Put them together into a dashboardPage
ui<-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  sidebar,
  body
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is it possible to create permalinks for the pages? e.g. the home page (`tabName` == "dashboard") has a URL of 127.0.0.1:1234/home and the widgets page is at 127.0.0.1:1234/widgets?

It seems that `shiny` doesn't have URL routing out of the box. `shiny.router` seems to be a possible alternative but I've found no easy ways to do this with `shinydashboard` i.e. with the use of `menuItem` and `tabItem`. I'm trying to avoid rewriting the app's UI to use something which is more tightly integrated with `shiny.router` (e.g. `shiny.semantic`)

Is it possible to keep the above `shinydashboard` code while implementing permalinks to the various different pages?

Comment: I think the `session$clientData$url_<xxxx>` elements will allow you to construct the necessary links programmatically.  See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/session.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll be honest, this is way over my head. I have a background in Django development so I'm familiar with URL routing. Shiny apps really kill my brain, sometimes.

Comment: It seems that shinydashboard adds some js that makes it impossible to integrate it with shiny.router:

https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.router/issues/20

If you don't neeed to do a production.grade app, you can check brochure:

https://github.com/ColinFay/brochure

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding {brochure}. Although this sounds promising, I'm reluctant to use a library which says not to use (and one that hasn't been updated since February). I did make some progress yesterday getting `shiny.router` working with `shinydashboard`. However, all the pages' content renders on a single page, which likely ties in with your assertion that they can't be integrated.

Comment: @Simon could you provide your progress with `shiny.routers` and `shinydashboard` on a single page? Im curious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541259/uri-routing-with-shiny-router-and-navbarpage-in-a-r-shiny-app/71807248#71807248) is how to use the below approach with shiny's `tabPanel()` function.

---

Workarounds not using `library(shiny.router)`:

**Edit** - Alternative using `clientData$url_search` and `mode = "push"` for `updateQueryString` to push a new history entry onto the browser's history stack:

[image: result]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(request) {
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebarID",
        menuItem(
          "Dashboard",
          tabName = "dashboard",
          icon = icon("tachometer-alt")
        ),
        menuItem(
          "Widgets",
          icon = icon("th"),
          tabName = "widgets",
          badgeLabel = "new",
          badgeColor = "green"
        )
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Dashboard tab content")),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content"))
    ))
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # http://127.0.0.1:6172/?tab=dashboard
  # http://127.0.0.1:6172/?tab=widgets
  
  observeEvent(getQueryString(session)$tab, {
    currentQueryString <- getQueryString(session)$tab # alternative: parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$tab
    if(is.null(input$sidebarID) || !is.null(currentQueryString) && currentQueryString != input$sidebarID){
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "sidebarID")
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebarID", selected = currentQueryString)
    }
  }, priority = 1)
  
  observeEvent(input$sidebarID, {
    currentQueryString <- getQueryString(session)$tab # alternative: parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$tab
    pushQueryString <- paste0("?tab=", input$sidebarID)
    if(is.null(currentQueryString) || currentQueryString != input$sidebarID){
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "sidebarID")
      updateQueryString(pushQueryString, mode = "push", session)
    }
  }, priority = 0)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "disable")
```

---

**Another Edit - using url_hash (uri fragments)**:

[image: result_fragments]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(request) {
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebarID",
        menuItem(
          "Dashboard",
          tabName = "dashboard",
          icon = icon("tachometer-alt")
        ),
        menuItem(
          "Widgets",
          icon = icon("th"),
          tabName = "widgets",
          badgeLabel = "new",
          badgeColor = "green"
        )
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Dashboard tab content")),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content"))
    ))
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$sidebarID, {
    # http://127.0.0.1:6172/#dashboard
    # http://127.0.0.1:6172/#widgets
    clientData <- reactiveValuesToList(session$clientData)
    newURL <- with(clientData, paste0(url_protocol, "//", url_hostname, ":", url_port, url_pathname, "#", input$sidebarID))
    updateQueryString(newURL, mode = "replace", session)
  })
  
  observe({
    currentTab <- sub("#", "", session$clientData$url_hash)
    if(!is.null(currentTab)){
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebarID", selected = currentTab)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "disable")
```

---

**Edit - using url_search**: Actually we can do the same without bookmarking using `getQueryString` and `updateTabItems`:

[image: result_without_bookmarking]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(request) {
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebarID",
        menuItem(
          "Dashboard",
          tabName = "dashboard",
          icon = icon("tachometer-alt")
        ),
        menuItem(
          "Widgets",
          icon = icon("th"),
          tabName = "widgets",
          badgeLabel = "new",
          badgeColor = "green"
        )
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Dashboard tab content")),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content"))
    ))
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$sidebarID, {
    # http://127.0.0.1:6172/?tab=dashboard
    # http://127.0.0.1:6172/?tab=widgets
    clientData <- reactiveValuesToList(session$clientData)
    newURL <- with(clientData, paste0(url_protocol, "//", url_hostname, ":", url_port, url_pathname, "?tab=", input$sidebarID))
    updateQueryString(newURL, mode = "replace", session)
    # updateQueryString(newURL, mode = "push", session)
  })

  observe({
    currentTab <- getQueryString(session)$tab # alternative: parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$tab
    if(!is.null(currentTab)){
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebarID", selected = currentTab)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "disable")
```

---

**Using bookmarks**:

Not sure if you are interested in a workaround like this, but you could use shiny's bookmarking and `updateQueryString` to achive a similar behaviour:

[image: result]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(request) {
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebarID",
        menuItem(
          "Dashboard",
          tabName = "dashboard",
          icon = icon("tachometer-alt")
        ),
        menuItem(
          "Widgets",
          icon = icon("th"),
          tabName = "widgets",
          badgeLabel = "new",
          badgeColor = "green"
        )
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Dashboard tab content")),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content"))
    ))
  )
}


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  bookmarkingWhitelist <- c("sidebarID")
  
  observe({
    setBookmarkExclude(setdiff(names(input), bookmarkingWhitelist))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$sidebarID, {
    # http://127.0.0.1:6172/?_inputs_&sidebarID=%22dashboard%22
    # http://127.0.0.1:6172/?_inputs_&sidebarID=%22widgets%22
    
    newURL <- paste0(
        session$clientData$url_protocol,
        "//",
        session$clientData$url_hostname,
        ":",
        session$clientData$url_port,
        session$clientData$url_pathname,
        "?_inputs_&sidebarID=%22",
        input$sidebarID,
        "%22"
      )
    
    updateQueryString(newURL,
                      mode = "replace",
                      session)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Some related links:

- https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/behavior.html#bookmarking
- https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/session.html
- [It is possible to restore a session, locally, in a Shiny app if the inputs have been previously written in a RDS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267644/it-is-possible-to-restore-a-session-locally-in-a-shiny-app-if-the-inputs-have/68253464#68253464)
- [shinyjs - setBookmarkExclude for delay IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816861/shinyjs-setbookmarkexclude-for-delay-ids/55825515#55825515)
- https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3546

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: @ismirsehregal, Do you know of a way to use URI routing with a dashboard that uses a navbarPage structure? Regarding this problem I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541259/uri-routing-with-shiny-router-and-navbarpage-in-a-r-shiny-app).