# URI routing with shiny.router and navbarPage in a R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use `shiny.router` to create shareable links to tabs of a shiny app that uses `navbarPage` and `tabPanel`.

Here is reproducible example that does not work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.router)

page_1 <- tabPanel("Page 1", value = "page_1",
                   "This is Page 1")

page_2 <- tabPanel("Page 2", value = "page_2",
                   "This is Page 2")

router <- make_router(
  route("/", page_1),
  route("page2", page_2)
)

#+++++++++++++
# ui
#+++++++++++++

ui <- navbarPage("Dashboard", theme = shinytheme("flatly"), 

      router$ui
)

#+++++++++++++
# server
#+++++++++++++

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  router$server(input, output, session)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It kind of works if I use for the ui part this code:

```
#+++++++++++++
# ui
#+++++++++++++

ui <- navbarPage("Dashboard", theme = shinytheme("flatly"),

  tabPanel(
    tags$ul(
      tags$li(a(href = route_link("/"), "Page 1")),
      tags$li(a(href = route_link("page2"), "Page 2"))
    ),
  router$ui
  )

)
```

But that does not leave me with a proper looking navbar. Is ist possible to use a `navbarPage` and `tabPanel` structure with `shiny.router`?

Comment: This is also my question! So far I've resorted to not using tabPanel but using fluidRow() and column() instead and then creating the navbar in CSS as shown in the shiny.router demo but I'd rather use navbar and shinythemes if possible.

Comment: @jantau thanks for the ping on my old post. I left an answer below. Cheers

Comment: @MyNameisTK just FYI below is another approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a slightly modified version of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70093686/9841389), which avoids using `library(shiny.router)`.

The difference is using `shiny::updateNavbarPage` instead of `shinydashboard::updateTabItems`:

```
# remotes::install_github("rstudio/shinythemes")

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- navbarPage(title = "Dashboard", id = "navbarID", theme = shinytheme("flatly"), 
                 tabPanel("Page 1", value = "page_1", "This is Page 1"),
                 tabPanel("Page 2", value = "page_2", "This is Page 2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$navbarID, {
    # http://127.0.0.1:3252/#page_1
    # http://127.0.0.1:3252/#page_2
    
    newURL <- paste0(
      session$clientData$url_protocol,
      "//",
      session$clientData$url_hostname,
      ":",
      session$clientData$url_port,
      session$clientData$url_pathname,
      "#",
      input$navbarID
    )
    updateQueryString(newURL, mode = "replace", session)
  })
  
  observe({
    currentTab <- sub("#", "", session$clientData$url_hash) # might need to wrap this with `utils::URLdecode` if hash contains encoded characters (not the case here)
    if(!is.null(currentTab)){
      updateNavbarPage(session, "navbarID", selected = currentTab)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

The above is using `clientData$url_hash` - the same could be done with `clientData$url_search` as shown in my earlier answer.

---

**Edit:** using `mode = "push"` in `updateQueryString` for browser navigation:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- navbarPage(title = "Dashboard", id = "navbarID", theme = shinytheme("flatly"), 
                 tabPanel("Page 1", value = "page_1", "This is Page 1"),
                 tabPanel("Page 2", value = "page_2", "This is Page 2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(session$clientData$url_hash, {
    currentHash <- sub("#", "", session$clientData$url_hash)
    if(is.null(input$navbarID) || !is.null(currentHash) && currentHash != input$navbarID){
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "navbarID")
      updateNavbarPage(session, "navbarID", selected = currentHash)
    }
  }, priority = 1)
  
  observeEvent(input$navbarID, {
    currentHash <- sub("#", "", session$clientData$url_hash) # might need to wrap this with `utils::URLdecode` if hash contains encoded characters (not the case here)
    pushQueryString <- paste0("#", input$navbarID)
    if(is.null(currentHash) || currentHash != input$navbarID){
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "navbarID")
      updateQueryString(pushQueryString, mode = "push", session)
    }
  }, priority = 0)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Alternative** using `clientData$url_search` and `mode = "push"`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- navbarPage(title = "Dashboard", id = "navbarID", theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                 tabPanel("Page 1", value = "page_1", "This is Page 1"),
                 tabPanel("Page 2", value = "page_2", "This is Page 2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(getQueryString(session)$page, {
    currentQueryString <- getQueryString(session)$page # alternative: parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$page
    if(is.null(input$navbarID) || !is.null(currentQueryString) && currentQueryString != input$navbarID){
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "navbarID")
      updateNavbarPage(session, "navbarID", selected = currentQueryString)
    }
  }, priority = 1)

  observeEvent(input$navbarID, {
    currentQueryString <- getQueryString(session)$page # alternative: parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$page
    pushQueryString <- paste0("?page=", input$navbarID)
    if(is.null(currentQueryString) || currentQueryString != input$navbarID){
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "navbarID")
      updateQueryString(pushQueryString, mode = "push", session)
    }
  }, priority = 0)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

PS: restoring a selected tab is also possible using shiny's [bookmarking capabilities](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html), as long as the `navbarPage` is provided with an `id`.

PPS: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74852297/want-secondary-navigation-tabs-using-r-shiny-router/74874638#74874638) a related question on a `navbarPage` using secondary navigation can be found.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggested solution. It is a pity that browser navigation does not work with this solution. However, it is worth a lot to me to have permanent tab links that I can share. And I am glad that I can continue to use navbarPage.

Comment: @jantau we can use `mode = push` in `updateQueryString` to enable browser navigation. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for another addition to your answer. I noticed that the solution with browser navigation does not route directly to a tab of the dashboard if it was not cached before. It works without prior caching in your first answer (the one without browser navigation). Ideally I would like to have both: link directly to a tab and have browser navigation. Can you think of a way to combine both solutions? If not, I will use your first answer.

Comment: @jantau - thanks for pointing this out - it was a initialization problem when `input$navbarID == NULL` on startup. I've had another look at the code and updated both approaches. Furhtermore, I accidentally introduced a [circular reference](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#circular-references) by switching to `mode = push`. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot, this works great. Now, the "show next page" browser navigation works, too.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround I took class tags from shinytheme("flatly") source code and applied them individually to ul() and a().  I'd rather use navbarPage() if possible.

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.router)


home_page <- div(
  titlePanel("Dashboard"),
  p("This is a dashboard page")
)

settings_page <- div(
  titlePanel("Settings"),
  p("This is a settings page")
)

contact_page <- div(
  titlePanel("Contact"),
  p("This is a contact page")
)


router <- make_router(
  route("/", home_page),
  route("settings", settings_page),
  route("contact", contact_page)
)


ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),


tags$ul(class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary",
        a(class="navbar-brand", href = route_link("/"), "Dashboard"),
        a(class="navbar-brand", href = route_link("settings"), "Settings"),
        a(class="navbar-brand", href = route_link("contact"), "Contact")
        ),
router$ui
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
router$server(input, output, session)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the workaround. I am working on a complex dashboard that uses navbarPage and I would like to prevent major rebuilds of the dashboard. On a new project I would probably use your solution with fluidPage, because I think URI routing is really important for a good ux.